# Looking for specific data using SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

MySQL - Looking for specific data using SELECT

I am looking for a way to do some SELECT and return only specific data from my database, here is an example of the data:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | aaaa | aaaa   | Yes    | True   |
|  2 | aaaa | bbbb   | Yes    | False  |
|  3 | aaaa | cccc   | Yes    | True   |
|  4 | aaaa | dddd   | Yes    | False  |
|  5 | aaaa | eeee   | Yes    | False  |
|  6 | bbbb | NULL   | Yes    | True   |
|  7 | bbbb | NULL   | Yes    | False  |
|  8 | bbbb | NULL   | Yes    | True   |
|  9 | bbbb | NULL   | Yes    | False  |
| 10 | cccc | ffff   | No     | True   |
| 11 | cccc | ffff   | No     | False  |
| 12 | cccc | ffff   | No     | True   |
| 13 | cccc | ffff   | No     | False  |
| 14 | cccc | gggg   | Yes    | True   |
| 15 | cccc | gggg   | Yes    | False  |
| 16 | cccc | gggg   | Yes    | True   |
| 17 | cccc | gggg   | Yes    | False  |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Here are the results I am expecting:

Results 1 (first SELECT):

```
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | aaaa | aaaa   | Yes    | True   |
|  2 | aaaa | bbbb   | Yes    | False  |
|  3 | aaaa | cccc   | Yes    | True   |
|  4 | aaaa | dddd   | Yes    | False  |
|  5 | aaaa | eeee   | Yes    | False  |
|  6 | bbbb | NULL   | Yes    | True   |
| 10 | cccc | ffff   | No     | True   |
| 14 | cccc | gggg   | Yes    | True   |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

NOTE:

- The column name result must follow the following restrictions:

  - The name must be unique unless:

    - There is another entry of name with a different value1, in which case, all the different name/value1 combos must be returned (this is mostly shown with IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 14 in the table, IDs 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17 are not in the results because of that restriction).
- The column value1 result must follow the following restrictions:

  - The value1 must return all different value1 entries (according to the name restrictions), but they must not be repeated (this is mostly shown with IDs 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 in the table, IDs 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17 are not in the results because of that restriction).
- The column value2 result has no restrictions.

Results 2 (second SELECT):

```
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | aaaa | aaaa   | Yes    | True   |
|  3 | aaaa | cccc   | Yes    | True   |
|  6 | bbbb | NULL   | Yes    | True   |
| 10 | cccc | ffff   | No     | True   |
| 14 | cccc | gggg   | Yes    | True   |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

NOTE:

- The column name result must follow the following restrictions:

  - The name must be unique unless:

    - There is another entry of name with a different value1, in which case, all the different name/value1 combos must be returned (this is mostly shown with IDs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 14 in the table, IDs 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17 are not in the results because of that restriction).
- The column value1 result must follow the following restrictions:

  - The value1 must return all different value1 entries (according to the name restrictions), but they must not be repeated (this is mostly shown with IDs 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 in the table, IDs 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17 are not in the results because of that restriction).
- The column value2 result has no restrictions.
- The column value3 result must follow the following restrictions:

  - The value3 must be TRUE.

Unfortunately, after some tests using SELECT with DISTINCT myself, I have no more ideas how to approach this, may someone help me out with this please?

Test 1:

```
select distinct name
from table1
```

Comment:
Does not take into account the restrictions of value1.

Test 2:

```
SELECT r.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id)
        FROM table1 t2
        WHERE t2.value1 <> ''
       ) as cnt
FROM (SELECT table1.name FROM table1) r;
```

Comment:
Does not take into account the restrictions of value1. I was trying to use count to see the number of returned results, my production environment got 14000 or so rows.

I am not an expert in MySQL as you might have guessed.

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: For the sake of clarity, I changed the column values in value2 and I completely rewrote the notes sections.

Comment: In your NOTE(s): "is the same" does that refer to the previous record? and, if so, is the order of the records (unique) determined by `ID` ?

Comment: Why did you not include the "several tests"? We (the reader on SO) now have no idea on what approaches you already tried, an why they failed.

Comment: Also, please note that `DISTINCT` is not some Magic keyword that will solve all your problems. Why do you think you even need `DISTINCT` to solve this?

Comment: I will edit my post, I did not keep all the tests I did, but I will gladly provide some. I will also specify what I meant with "the same".

Comment: Your specification did NOT make your question easier to read.

Comment: I will completely rewrite the post.

Answer (score 1):

Result1:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   name,
   value1,
   value2,
   CASE value3 WHEN 0 THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END as value3
FROM specificData
WHERE value2 IS NULL or value2 ='aaaa';
```

output for reault1 (based on your input data):

```
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID   | name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 | aaaa | aaaa   | NULL   | True   |
|    2 | aaaa | bbbb   | NULL   | False  |
|    3 | aaaa | cccc   | NULL   | True   |
|    4 | aaaa | dddd   | NULL   | False  |
|    5 | aaaa | eeee   | NULL   | False  |
|    6 | bbbb | NULL   | aaaa   | True   |
|   10 | cccc | aaaa   | aaaa   | True   |
|   14 | cccc | bbbb   | aaaa   | True   |
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Result2:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   name,
   value1,
   value2,
   CASE value3 WHEN 0 THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END as value3
FROM specificData
WHERE (value2 IS NULL or value2 ='aaaa') 
  AND value3;
```

output for result2(based on your input data):

```
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID   | name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 | aaaa | aaaa   | NULL   | True   |
|    3 | aaaa | cccc   | NULL   | True   |
|    6 | bbbb | NULL   | aaaa   | True   |
|   10 | cccc | aaaa   | aaaa   | True   |
|   14 | cccc | bbbb   | aaaa   | True   |
+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

DISCLAIMER:
While the above results meet the desired output, the queries are NOT guaranteed the ones that you need! This is because the description is pretty unclear.

Finally script to generate your testdata (in case someone else needs this ):

```
CREATE TABLE specificData (ID INTEGER, name VARCHAR(10), value1 VARCHAR(10), value2 VARCHAR(10), value3 Boolean);
INSERT INTO specificData VALUES 
(1,'aaaa','aaaa',NULL,True),
(2,'aaaa','bbbb',NULL,False),
(3,'aaaa','cccc',NULL,True),
(4,'aaaa','dddd',NULL,False),
(5,'aaaa','eeee',NULL,False),
(6,'bbbb',NULL,'aaaa',True),
(7,'bbbb',NULL,'bbbb',False),
(8,'bbbb',NULL,'cccc',True),
(9,'bbbb',NULL,'dddd',False),
(10,'cccc','aaaa','aaaa',True),
(11,'cccc','aaaa','bbbb',False),
(12,'cccc','aaaa','cccc',True),
(13,'cccc','aaaa','dddd',False),
(14,'cccc','bbbb','aaaa',True),
(15,'cccc','bbbb','bbbb',False),
(16,'cccc','bbbb','cccc',True),
(17,'cccc','bbbb','dddd',False);
```